# pass object in function parameter to clone in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters

I am calling function with parameter.

> clonDiv(num7);

Here is code

```
        function clonDiv(div) {
        div.id = "'#"+div.id+"'";  //here i am trying to turn it into sting
        $(div.id).clone().addClass('copy').appendTo("#container");
        }
```

but can't pass parameter like that.
To make code work i need to pass div id like that

```
clonDiv("#num7");
```

> ```
>         function clonDiv(div) {
>         $(div).clone().addClass('copy').appendTo("#container");
>         }
> ```

But i would like to just pass it like that clonDiv(num7); and in the function describe all quotes.
Parameter in the function is an object.

div structure of that object

> ```
> <div id="num7" class="box resizable draggable ui-resizable selected"></div>
> ```

clonDiv(num7); i am calling from textarea using eval();

Comment: what exactly is the problem? it's really not clear.

Comment: I don't know how to pass function parameter in this jquery construction $("#parameter") to make it work

Comment: If you want get id from div element use `$(div).attr(id)` or `$(div)[0].id`

Comment: Yeah i can get elem.id. but i can pass it into $("#")

Comment: can you provide some more code? html structure/elements/how exactly you call the `clonDiv` function? etc...

Comment: do you want to call it `clonDiv('num7')`?

Comment: Try this code https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/anah3p7e/

Comment: CMedina it's should work. alert is accurate. But again jquery doesn't understand it.. Clone doesn't work. I am using jquery v2.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that num7 is a jquery object or and ID already (prefixed with #), you should be able to clone it directly:

```
function clonDiv(div) {
   $(div).clone().addClass('copy').appendTo("#container");
}
```

But as you should also change the ID, standards specify that HTML element id's should be unique, I'd probably also send the ID for the new element

```
function clonDiv(div, newId) {
   $(div).clone().attr('id', newId).addClass('copy').appendTo("#container");
}
```

And invoke it like

```
clonDiv(num7, 'num8');
```

Comment: Thank you! And for the for  the newId solution another tnanx, wow.

Comment: I don't understand how i missed $(div). I certainly tried it.

Answer (score 1):

it strikes me that this is what you are after;

```
function clonDiv(id){
   $("#" + id).clone().addClass('copy').appendTo($('#container'));
}

clonDiv('num7');
```

Comment: it works, but i am asking is it possible to do clonDiv(num7); without anything else)

Comment: that is hard to answer without knowing what `num7` is.  Is it a jquery object, element, string or number?

Comment: object. probably jquery. well it's "object htmldivelement"